# Vector Space Questions

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi there I have a few quick Vector Space Questions that I am really confused about.

Label the following as true or false:
1)In any vector space, ax=bx implies a=b
2)In any vector space, ax=ay implies that x=y

Note: a and b are the members of a field, and x is a member of the vector space.

For number 1, the answer is no because if you let *e* be the zero vecto, we have 1e=2e.
That is the answer in the solution manual, but I don't get how they got 1e=2e? Also, the zero vector isn't just 0? You can define it to be anything you want?

For number 2, the answer is no because if you let a=0, it will not be true. I was wondering why that is, because if you let a=0, then you would end up with 0 is equal to 0....

Anyway, if anyone can clarify these 2 questions for me, that would be awesome!

Comment: $0*(1,1,1)=0*(2,2,2)=(0,0,0)$ But $(1,1,1) \neq (2,2,2)$

Answer (score 0):

The first question asks if for any $a, b \in \mathbb{F}$ and $x \in V,$

$$ ax = bx \implies a = b. $$

Totally doesn't work as you saw above!  Clearly $1(0) = 2(0)$ but $1 \neq 2$. While we do have zero equals zero in the first, the scalars themselves aren't equal. So we can't cancel vectors in this fashion!

The second works the same way, except now you fix the scalar. Hmm... Maybe choosing $a=0$ should do the trick and selecting nonzero $x$ and $y.$ Same argument.